# How we add a cookie value to an existing cookie in php

Tags: php

this my code but i am not getting the my cookie value in page

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['mycookie'])) {

    $cookie[] = $proID;
    $cookie = implode(',', $cookie);
    $cookie = unserialize($cookie);
    setcookie('mycookie', serialize($cookie), time() + (86400 * 30), '/');

}
```

Comment: Where do you set $proID ?

Comment: i am posting to my page

Comment: if the cookie is not set i use  $cookie=array();
    $cookie[] = $proID;
    $cookie = serialize($cookie);
   
    setcookie('mycookie',$cookie,time() + (86400 * 30),"/");

Comment: why would you first `implode` an array than `unserialize` to `serialize` it in the next step. Looks to me as unnecessary

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421154/how-to-add-edit-a-cookie-in-php

Comment: Please help me to how we set a cookie and add extra  value to that cookie on each time when we on the page

Comment: $cookie_data['foo'] = 'bar';
setcookie("mycookies",serialize($cookies_array),time()+60*60*24*30); didnt understand $cookie_data['foo'] = 'bar';

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `isset($_COOKIE['mycookie'])` which will check if the `$_COOKIE['mycookie']` is set or not, will return `true` if set else `false`. And if you are setting it inside the `if` block for the first time it will never be set. So it should be -

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['mycookie']))
    // Set the cookie   
}
```

Comment: $cookie=array();
    $cookie[] = $proID;
    $cookie = serialize($cookie);
   
    setcookie('mycookie',$cookie,time() + (86400 * 30),"/"); if cookie not set

Comment: Then you just have to add a `negation` to `isset`. Check the answer.

Comment: sorry i didnt understand what u said

Comment: if (isset($_COOKIE['mycookie'])) {
   $cookie[] = $proID;
   $cookie = implode(',', $cookie);
   $cookie = serialize($cookie);
 setcookie('mycookie', $cookie, time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
  }
  else{
  $cookie=array();
    $cookie[] = $proID;
    $cookie = serialize($cookie);
   
    setcookie('mycookie',$cookie,time() + (86400 * 30),"/");
 } this my whole code

Answer (score 0):

First get the old value of the cookie, and turn it into an array with `unserialize`. If the cookie isn't set, initialize it to an empty array.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['mycookie'])) {
    $cookie = unserialize($_COOKIE['mycookie']);
} else {
    $cookie = array();
}
```

Then add the new element to the array, and save it back into the cookie.

```
$cookie[] = $proID;
setcookie('mycookie', serialize($cookie), time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
```

Comment: Thanks , i tried but value is not appending if the cookie already set the code is used : if (isset($_COOKIE['mycookie'])) {
    $cookie = unserialize($_COOKIE['mycookie']);
 $cookie[] = $proID;
setcookie('mycookie', serialize($cookie), time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
 
} else {
    $cookie = array();
 $cookie[] = $proID;
setcookie('mycookie', serialize($cookie), time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
}

Comment: Do you get an error? Are you reloading the page when you do this? `$_COOKIE` doesn't get updated when you call `setcookie()`, only when the script first starts.

Comment: a:1:{i:0;s:2:\"12\";}<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent  each time when i go to different product it update but i cant see the previous product id

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: but i cant see the data appending each updates i got different id not showing two or more id

Comment: If you get the `headers already sent` error, it doesn't update the cookie. You have to fix that, and the question I linked to explains how.

Comment: warning is shwing beacuse as a testing i am echoing the cookie value

Comment: Don't do that. You can use the browser's console to see cookies.

Comment: $cookie[] = $proID;
setcookie('mycookie', serialize($cookie), time() + (86400 * 30), '/');                   $cookie[] is not appending data to the old value it updating the id with new id

Comment: i tried but but still new value not appending to old data

Comment: I just tried it and it works for me. Every time I reload the page, another element is added to the cookie.

Comment: mycookies
 a:1:{i:0;s:2:"17";}

Comment: another page it showing mycookies
 a:1:{i:0;s:2:"17";}

Comment: Make sure all of them specify the pathname `/` when setting the cookie. By default they use the directory that the script is in.

Comment: if (isset($_COOKIE['mycookie'])) {
$cookie = array();
    $cookie = unserialize($_COOKIE['mycookie']);
  
 $cookie[] = $proID;
 $cookie = implode(',', $cookie);

setcookie('mycookie', serialize($cookie), time() + (86400 * 30), '/');

 
} else { 
    $cookie = array();
 $cookie[] = $proID;
setcookie('mycookie', serialize($cookie), time() + (86400 * 30), '/');
} this is my code can u p-lease check it is working for u

Comment: Don't use `implode(',', $cookie)`.

Comment: Use the code exactly as it is in my answer. I tested it and it works.

Comment: it tried it shows a:1:{i:0;s:2:"17";} on the first page and a:1:{i:0;s:2:"12";}

Comment: Sorry, I can't tell what you're doing differently.

Comment: i used ur code but when ever i got new product page i am getting the cookie but it nor showing the previous product id on that

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, sorry.